# Hanging a TV on the wall when it partially overlaps a window

Tags: mounting, television

I have a new 55" TV that we currently have on a stand. I have two young children and I'd much rather have it mounted on the wall. This will add security to it and keep it a bit father away from greasy finger prints.

The main problem is that the TV overlaps a window by nearly 40%. I'm afraid that finding a wall mount will be next to impossible. It would need to be able to offset itself by a good deal. I have 2X wooden studs within the first 6 inches of the window well, so I'd be good on a secure place to mount into if I could find a mount with an arm.

[image: TV on wall with window]
Bonus points! My kitchen is to the right of this photo and I'd love it if I could rotate the TV 45 degrees or so and occassionally watch it while cooking. I know this is a tall order but I was hoping the DIY community might have some solutions. I'm fairly handy and I'm open to ideas and questions.

Comment: I don't think you did much, if any, research.  In a single Google search I found at least four (and stopped looking at it) 55" full motion arm style mounts.   Also, technically this is a shopping question, which is off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: long reach tv arm mount]

This particular model provides a reach for the mounted television of a maximum of 29", which is astonishing (opinion) and according to the ad copy, allows a 90° turn for up to a 55" television set. This would appear to meet and exceed your requirements of about 45°. It's pricey, but not compared to the prices of large televisions that get knocked about.

As Tyson suggests, a Google search for "long reach wide television arm mount" would give you a wide selection. The one pictured above can be found [here.](https://www.av-express.com/full-motion-tv-wall-mount-long-extension-32-to-65-Inch-AEON-40112?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIrofUxKGa2QIVEiOBCh2ovgbQEAQYAyABEgKIifD_BwE)